# Decision between 1 dedicated server or multiple vps

Tags: sql, web-hosting, vps, dedicated-server

I'm searching for my company the best possible setup for hosting multiple projects with a budget of ~100-150$ per month.

We need to put on the server(s):

- 1x MS SQL-Server (medium-high load)
- 4x Webcrawler (4 website requests per second, 24/7 runtime)
- 1x ASP.Net Webshop
- 1x ASP.Net Backend for our webshop
- 2x Small ASP.Net Websites

The requirements are, that the SQL shouldn't be the bottleneck and of course we need the highest possible uptime for our webshop and our backend.

Is it better to put everything on one dedicated server or should I split them up and put them on multiple VPS?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, multiple VPS (Clustering) would be an ideal approach to be followed.Rather using single powerful dedicated server to host all services together, clustering has significant benefits such as highest availability, load distribution and low-cost VPS.

In your case, the ideal solution would be placing your web server (IIS) and database server (MS SQL Server) on two separate VPS. IIS web server will handle web requests communicating with isolated MS SQL server. Such configuration can be easily established with the help of control panels. For Windows based servers, WebsitePanel (FREE) and Plesk Panel are the most trusted control panels available. This control panel will be installed on one of your VPS and all your web services/servers such as SQL Server, IIS web server, Mail server (if any) will get integrated with this control panel. Thus, you can manage IIS and SQL server through single login of control panel.

Additionally, not all servers have the same requirements. IIS Web Server and MS SQL Server will have different server requirements. Web server will be storing the web contents and websites. These websites may contain images, videos file etc. Hence, web server requires more hard disk space than SQL Server.

On the other hand, MS SQL server always been resource hungry and it requires more RAM and CPU power. Additionally, while you host MS SQL server you will have huge I/O. Thus, it is highly recommended to host MS SQL Server on SSD drives.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed opinion. I can follow you in terms of requirements for servers. (SSD, RAM, CPU etc.)
But I didn't really get the advantage of using Plesk or WebsitePanel. Could  you tell me, what benefits I get from using them?

Comment: I mean I'm pretty used to setting up Databases and IIS configuration, so as far as I understood those panels just give me a GUI for setting up IIS and SQL ?!

Comment: That's true ... they will give you GUI for setting up websites. You can easily setup domains, email accounts, ftp accounts and databases using these control panels.